# Programmers clipboard monitor under Windows

Tags: windows

In the process of adapting a "put on clipboard"-solution to new behavior I have found that I need a good *programmers* clipboard monitor for Windows.

I do not need to have a history of items on the clipboard, but I need to see the details of what is currently placed there, including - this is important - the various flavors (RTF/HTML/plain text/etc) to be sure that all those I place there are correct.  Free is preferred, but cheap will do.

We are a Java shop, but I can install a Visual Studio Express edition if that makes things easier.

(EDIT: The development box is Windows 7 64-bit)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn, questions about programming tools and recommendations thereof aren't on-topic here, but it's not clear you're looking for something that's specifically for programmers. If you can phrase it more in terms of the development problem you're trying to solve rather than a list of programs, it'll likely work on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkTrapp, I ask for a "Programmers clipboard monitor"?  I state that my need is to be able to see all flavors of what is put on the clipboard, to be certain I do it right.  I do not have a development problem, I need a tool.  Please reopen.

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq): "If you have a question about [...] and it is not about programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)". You're welcome to attempt to ask this on Stack Overflow, but I did check with the mods there to see if it was okay to migrate this, and they weren't convinced this had anything to do with programming. So you're going to have to make it a little more clear why this is specific to programming beyond just saying it's a programmer tool.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I read the "not about programming tools" part as a "we do not want questions about how to use feature X in program Y here, ask on SO", not as a "do not ask anything _at all_ about tools".

Comment: It includes "What tool should I use for X?", which is on-topic on Stack Overflow, although many such questions fall into the trap of the [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which is off-topic everywhere.

Comment: This is clearly a programmer's tool. I don't know why a non-programmer would use a tool like this. IMHO, I'm not happy with the trend to close more and more questions for bureaucratic reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [FreeClipBoardViewer](http://freeclipboardviewer.com/) without issues.

It allows you to view the different formats stored on the clipboard, and export them. It also allows importing a previous export so you can transfer clipboards between computers and restore an earlier clipboard in order to do testing or debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The **ClipBook Viewer** is a Windows utility, that exist since the **initial** version of Windows and can be used to display the current contents of the "clipboard" and the type of clipboard contents (rtf, image etc.). Additionally, you can use it to manage the clipboard contents.

Unfortunately, the ClipBook Viewer **is not included in Windows 7**, so you should use another utility for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The system's built-in clipboard viewer, available under "Accesories," shows a list of the clipboard formats that are on the clipboard in a menu. Or at least it did up until at least Windows XP; I'm running Ubuntu at the moment so can't look at the Windows 7 version :)

You can select the different formats off that menu, and it'll render them on-screen, so far as it can.

EDIT: It's gone from Win 7? I has a sad; I owned it for a while, long long ago. The app is a bog-standard Win32 C application with no odd dependencies, so if you copy CLIPBOOK.EXE from a Windows XP installation you can probably run it under Windows 7. It'll complain about a "Clipbook Service" on startup, but shouldn't die about it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using Windows 7 x64 and I cannot identify such program in the Accessories menu.   Anyone know the name under Windows 7?